Nummelin (1984) Existence of Cycles of Irriducible Kernel
I am doing my second read on Nummelin's 1984 book "General Irriducible Markov Chains and Non-negative Operators" available for instance here https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/general-irreducible-markov-chains-and-nonnegative-operators/0557D49C011AA90B761FC854D5C14983. I try to fill details on the proof to theorem 2.2. There is one step I cannot understand.
Let $(E, F_E, \phi)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space on which let $K$ be an irriducible non-negative kernel. We suppose that $K$ is minorized. That is, there exists constants $m_0$, $\beta > 0$, measurable function $s \geqslant 0$ ($s>0$ somewhere) and positive measure $\nu$ ($\nu$ not identically zero) such that, for every $(x,A) \in E \times F_E$:
\begin{equation*}
K^{m_0}(x,A) \geqslant \beta s(x) \nu(A)
\end{equation*}
Now suppose that, for fixed positive integers $a$ and $b$, the following set $A$ has $\phi$-positive measure :
\begin{equation*}
A = \{K^as > 0\} \cap \{K^b s > 0\}
\end{equation*}
The author claims that, by irriducibility, on set $A$, there exists a non-negative integer $q$ such that $\nu K^{a + q}s>0$ and $\nu K^{b + q}s > 0$. It does not look very clear how to show this or reason through it intuitively.
